After Spring upgrade 3.0.2->3.3.2, Mockito's Mockito.any(Object.class) not mocking Object... (varargs) argument
We have code that executes RestTemplate.exchange() to execute an HTTP request, and a Unit Test that tests it. The expected params (5) are
@Override
public <T> ResponseEntity<T> exchange(String url, 
                                      HttpMethod method,
                                      @Nullable HttpEntity<?> requestEntity, 
                                      Class<T> responseType, 
                                      Object... uriVariables)
throws RestClientException {

The code line to be mocked is below (note the last varargs is omitted, which is OK):
responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(endpointUrl, 
                                       HttpMethod.POST, 
                                       requestEntity, 
                                       responseType);

Originally in Spring 3.0.2 the following Mockito line mocked the right conditions for us in our unit test:
MockedConstruction<RestTemplate> mockRC = Mockito.mockConstruction(RestTemplate.class,
    (mock, context) -> {
        when(mock.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), 
                           Mockito.any(HttpMethod.class), 
                           Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class), 
                           Mockito.any(Class.class), 
                           Mockito.any(Object.class)
        )).thenThrow(new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY));

But then after we upgraded to Spring 3.3.2 it no longer mocks correctly. My suspicion is that last varargs param is handled in some new way. Any thoughts?

This is a breaking change in Mockito 5 how varargs arguments are handled by matchers.
Spring Boot 3.0.2 pulled Mockito 4.8.1 while Spring Boot 3.1.0+ pulls at least Mockito 5.3.1 (Mockito 5.11.0 for current Spring Boot 3.3.2).
It's also documented in the JavaDoc of the ArgumentMatchers#any(Class) method:

Notes :

For primitive types use anyChar() family.
Since Mockito 2.1.0 this method will perform a type check thus null values are not authorized.
Since Mockito 2.1.0 any() is no longer an alias of this method.
Since Mockito 5.0.0 this method can match varargs if the array type is specified, for example any(String[].class).


So you will need to change your stub to either of the following:

Match no varargs (empty varargs array) passed – will match your specific call exactly:
 when(mock.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), 
                    Mockito.any(HttpMethod.class), 
                    Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class), 
                    Mockito.any(Class.class)))


Match any number of varargs passed – will match any call to the exchange method:
 when(mock.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), 
                    Mockito.any(HttpMethod.class), 
                    Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class), 
                    Mockito.any(Class.class), 
                    Mockito.any(Object[].class)))




Yes, mocking Object[].class (as opposed to Object.class) for the varargs ... parameter solved the problem. Thanks
